# Cannot log in to GNOME with XMonad sessions

Tags: gnome, lightdm, xmonad

I'm running ubuntu 14.04.3LTS. I recently installed xmonad via apt. When I log in, I have three options:

GNOME with Xmonad

Ubuntu (Default)

Xmonad

Ubuntu works fine, as does Xmonad. However, when I try to log in to GNOME with Xmonad, my desktop doesn't load; I'm instantly logged out. The .xsession-errors reads:

`Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped`

Does anyone have any advice to make GNOME with Xmonad work? I'm happy to post logs/answer details.

Thank you!